# Find every 2 alternate records in sql

Tags: mysql

I have an issue with a SQl Query. It's as below.

In a particular field the record consists of "A" and "B" only.

Now if I want to find 2 records of "A" followed by 2 records of "B" and then again 2 Records of "A" and 2 records of "B" and so on till the end of records.

```
example output should be something like below.
    ID        Field
---------     -----
    2           A
    3           A
    1           B
    5           B
    4           A
    7           A
    6           B
    8           B
.........
.........
```

.............. and so on

Kindly help me with the above....as am stuck for this query.

Thanks!

Comment: how your input records look like ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by enumerating the rows for each value and then cleverly ordering the results:

```
select id, field
from (select t.*,
             if(field = 'A', @a_rn := @a_rn + 1, @b_rn := @b_rn + 1) as rn
      from table t
           (select @a_rn := 0, @b_rn := 0) vars
     ) t
order by (rn - 1) div 2, field;
```

Answer (score 0):

or slower but cooler...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.field = x.field 
   AND y.id <= x.id 
 GROUP 
    BY field
     , id 
 ORDER 
    BY CEILING(COUNT(*)/2)
     , field;
```